# TinyMce editor not returning tags

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, rte

H7i guys, I am having a weird problem with the TinyMce editor. What I am trying to do is to select some text, click a button and append a tag at the start and at the end.

For example, if the original text is `<p>hello</p>`, the end text would be `<myTag><p>hello</p></myTag>`.

It works fine but when selecting a single line of text the existing tags are not returned. So in the previous example I would get `hello` only and not `<p>hello</p>`.

When I select multiple lines it returns the tags.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
            var se = ed.selection.getContent(); //Doesn't return tags on single line
            var be = ed.selection.getNode().outerHtml; //Doesn't work with multiline
            var ke = ed.selection.getContent({ format: 'raw' }); //Same as the first option
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to employ different functions to get the content, depending on the content the user selected

```
var node = ed.selection.getNode();

if (node.nodeName != 'P' )
{
     content = ed.selection.getContent();
}
else content = node.outerHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, works like a charm. The only proble is the you put `x.outerHtml` instead of `node.outerHTML`. Take note of the uppercase HTML as javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: correct, i changed the variable name while editing - will correct this asap

Answer (score 1):

I use this, and works well:

```
var textt= tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'text'});
alert(textt);
```

BUT NOTE: You should not select text from the start of a paragraph to the end of a paragraph,

[image]

because in that case(maybe bug of TinyMce), it cant get content .